# How to count the number of users who have rated 2 stars, 3stars, 4stars on a specific game in Django

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-templates

Am having a review model where users rate the game , 1star, 2star,3star,4star and 5star.

But l would like to count the number of users who have rated the game  with 1star , 2stars to 5stars.

As below in the **example:**

**Game:** Template run
**Ratings**

*1star:* 23,
*2star:* 34,
*3star:* 67,
*4star:* 45,
*5star:* 39

**Below it's my model for reviews**

```
RATING=[

    (1,"★"),

    (2,"★★"),

    (3,"★★★"),

    (4,"★★★★"),

    (5,"★★★★★"),

]

class ActionGameReview(models.Model):

    game_name =models.ForeignKey(ActionGame, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')

    user =models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    review =models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False)

    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=RATING)

    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.game_name.game_name

    class Meta:

        ordering=['-created_at']

        get_latest_by= str('created_at')
```

I don't know how do it, anyone to solve me

Answer (score 0):

you can try an aggregation with annotate:

```
query = ActionGameReview.objects.values('rating').annotate(rating_count=Count('rating'))
```

which will give you a query set like

```
<QuerySet [{'rating': 1, 'rating_count': 4}, {'rating': 2, 'rating_count': 17}, ....]>
```

Comment: Now in the template , how do l loop to get the total number of those that rated in every star level ?  Eg  " to get the total number of  those that rated the object with three stars only"